# Sensor data split

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, split

i want to split each string from data sensor that flow loop infinity/continously, each string i want to distribute to array index here is the sensor example

```
\r212 098 100 110 000 000 000 192 180 003 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 001 026
\r212 108 098 100 000 000 000 192 180 003 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 001 026
```

i want to extract data example from data 1 from 098 to 026 each string distribute on array, and i want identifier that the data length started by `/r212` , and split by `' '` ,

here is that already i do,the problem sometimes the value from for example array [2] sometimes replaced by array[3]. so example the value should be 098 it replaced by 100,

```
private void timer2_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imudata = portimu.ReadExisting(); 
            if (portimu.IsOpen)
            {
                string[] pjgdata = imudata.Split('\r');
                for (int i = 0; i < pjgdata.Length; i++)
                {
                    string datatemp = pjgdata[i];
                    DataSensor = datatemp.Split(' ');
                    if (DataSensor[0] == "212")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            txtAccX.Text = DataSensor[1];           //Akselero X,Y,Z
                            txtAccY.Text = DataSensor[2];
                            txtAccZ.Text = DataSensor[3];
                            txtGyroX.Text = DataSensor[4];
                            txtGyroY.Text = DataSensor[5];
                            txtGyroZ.Text = DataSensor[6];
                            txtPitch.Text = DataSensor[7];
                            txtRoll.Text = DataSensor[8];
                            txtYaw.Text = DataSensor[9];                
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }    
                }    
            }
        }
```

screenshot for data flows from my vs2010 debug n Hterm data [Here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/11156386_1588869788037572_1535764160055155856_n.jpg?oh=5709f8ed0b9cbfaa65c26bb0fd1dc4c7&oe=559BC3CC&__gda__=1440512499_6c31a556c0421e416869d857af4d8f6c)  the problem sometimes data from accY move to accX

Comment: "\rxxx" is a number such as \r001" ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue. Your code appears to flow correctly. The only thing I want to make clear on is if you are getting your 1st and 2nd row mixed up when you are debugging. Your example rows have `098 100` offset by a single index which it sounds like you are saying they are getting mixed up. I don't personally see anything wrong with your sample data and your supposed results. Can you explain?

Comment: XXX actually a number 212 it can be changed

Comment: You should put your image in your question and not link to it externally. The SO community prefers avoiding external links to help ensure questions remain intact in case the link dies in the future.

Comment: I too am confused with your question. I don't understand what is currently going wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, another suggestion - please never ever code `try { ... } catch { }`. It's very bad programming as it says "I know I'm writing code that can fail, but if it does please ignore it and don't tell me about it." Only put a `try`/`catch` in your code when you know that there are exceptions that you can't foresee, but must handle - like running out of hard drive space or a network connection dropping - and then **only** handle that specific exception.